# Is there a graph operation that describes the following phenomenon?

Tags: graph-theory

Consider the following graphs:

[image]

[image]

The first graph seems to be obtained by combining the second graph in some way with a 1-path. I could "extend" the graph (i.e. add more squares in a linear fashion) by combining the second graph with a longer path. Is there a graph operation that describes this? I have browsed the internet but have come up short.

Answer (score 3):

Your graphs are related via an operation called [series-parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series-parallel_graph). They can be obtained from $K_2$ by repeating the following operations :

1. Subdivide an edge
2. Duplicate an edge

[image]

There are some interesting results for Series-Parallel-graphs (e.g. a graph is SP if and only it does not $K_4$ as a minor)

**Edit** your operation of adding an external path would be related to adding an ear and looking for an [ear decomposition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ear_decomposition).

Comment: This is indeed a way to construct my graph but I am still hoping that there is a binary-like operation to combine my graph with a path graph (this is why I have not accepted your answer). Indeed, I only posted one particular example of the class of graphs I am hoping to apply this to.

Comment: I've added an comment. You could br interested in the ear concept.